# how to simplify the following code by using macro

Tags: c

```
strcpy(argv[0], arg0)
strcpy(argv[1], arg1)
strcpy(argv[2], arg2)
strcpy(argv[3], arg3)
strcpy(argv[4], arg4)
strcpy(argv[5], arg5)
strcpy(argv[6], arg6)
strcpy(argv[7], arg7)
strcpy(argv[8], arg8)
strcpy(argv[9], arg9)
```

I known the following is not right, but what is the right way to use macro?

```
#define ARG(i) arg##i
for (i = 0;i  < 10; i++)    
{    
strcpy(arg[i], ARG(i);    
}
```

Comment: You can't evaluate a runtime variable before compilation.

Comment: The first part argv is an array, but the second part looks like it's a straight variable. As far as I know, you cant pop the value of one variable on the end of another like that. It just wont work

Comment: Yes, yes ... with the emphasis on "**before**"!

Comment: Why not make `arg` an array?  Then the problem becomes simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed you can't use `##` like this.

This could work, although very awkward yet:

```
#define ARG(i) ((i==0)?arg0:(i==1)?arg1:(i==2)?arg2:(i==3)?arg3:(i==4)?arg4:(i==5)?arg5:(i==6)?arg6:(i==7)?arg7:(i==8)?arg8:(i==9)?arg9:0)
```

Comment: Although correct, I'd consider this quiet inefficient. Or does anybody feels this could be optimised by the compiler?

Comment: @ZhangBaolei Why? It doesn't compile?

Comment: yes, It doesn's compile, because "(i == 9)?arg9" is a uncomplete statment

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot the last part. If arg1 .. arg8 are pointers you should add `:0` as a null pointer in the end, as you said.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of simplifying your sequence of calls to `strcpy` you should rather convert you variables `arg0`, `arg1`, ..., `arg9` to an array. If you do it, you will be able to do the whole thing in a simple loop.

Comment: but arg0,...arg9 is fixed function varable name

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use arrays instead of macro in this case. It's much cleaner and don't have a lot of conditions evaluated at runtime;

```
char **args[10] = { &arg0, &arg1, &arg2, &arg3, &arg4, &arg5, &arg6, &arg7, &arg8, &arg9 };

for( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    strcpy( argv[i], *args[i] );
}
```

Comment: I think i will not compile, because **args[10] cannot be inialized with variables

Comment: @ZhangBaolei It will compile, tested with gcc

Answer (score 0):

use BOOST

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>


#define GEN_DEC(x, i, name) char* BOOST_PP_CAT(name, i);
#define GEN_FUNC(x, i, name) strcpy(argv[i], BOOST_PP_CAT(name, i));

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
BOOST_PP_REPEAT(10,GEN_DEC,arg)
BOOST_PP_REPEAT(10,GEN_FUNC,arg)

   return 0;
}
```

command line
`>gcc -I c:\boost_1_48_0 test.c`

check 
`>gcc -I c:\boost_1_48_0 test.c -E`

output sample

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
char* arg0; char* arg1; char* arg2; char* arg3; char* arg4; char* arg5; char* ar
g6; char* arg7; char* arg8; char* arg9;
strcpy(argv[0], arg0); strcpy(argv[1], arg1); strcpy(argv[2], arg2); strcpy(argv
[3], arg3); strcpy(argv[4], arg4); strcpy(argv[5], arg5); strcpy(argv[6], arg6);
 strcpy(argv[7], arg7); strcpy(argv[8], arg8); strcpy(argv[9], arg9);

   return 0;
}
```